# tcpdump doesn't get killed in Android

Tags: android, tcpdump

Why does it take tcpdump on android long time to start and when it starts and I want to kill it, the device gets stuck and doesn't kill it? When I try to kill the process, it doesn't work. Any suggestions on why is this happening?

Comment: how do you call tcpdump? and how you try to kill it?

Comment: from the terminal emulator, I type tcpdump to start capturing, but I can't kill it actually